# Check if subclass overrides a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

Is it possible to check whether a subclass implements a method that exists either in its immediate superclass or in some superclass of its superclass, etc?

E.g. I subclass `UIView`, to make my custom generic view for my app, and then I subclass this custom view. Now some of my subclasses override some method from `UIView` and some don't. I only want to call this method if it is actually overridden, I do not want the default `UIView` method being called.

Is there a way to check this, i.e. with a method similar to `respondsToSelector:`?

**Edit:** 
This question is different from the one asked in [Objective-C detect if class overrides inherited method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147203/objective-c-detect-if-class-overrides-inherited-method) because I do not really know or do not want to care which superclass originally implements the method.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147203/objective-c-detect-if-class-overrides-inherited-method

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this answer is that I do not exactly know which superclass originally implements the method, or more precisely I do not want to care about this.

Comment: This method can be adapted to be used recursively.

Comment: To be honest, this seems like quite a hacky solutions, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Wy dont you give your methods clear names. Call them myXXXX or similar and you will never have an superclass method at all.

Comment: This is not exactly my point, somewhere else in code I depend on the inheritance properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276997/2043580) by Mert Buran.

You can create a simple method to check whether a given object overrides a given selector (method):

```
-(BOOL)checkIfObject:(id)object overridesSelector:(SEL)selector {

    Class objSuperClass = [object superclass];
    BOOL isMethodOverridden = NO;

    while (objSuperClass != Nil) {

        isMethodOverridden = [object methodForSelector: selector] !=
        [objSuperClass instanceMethodForSelector: selector];

        if (isMethodOverridden) {
            break;
        }

        objSuperClass = [objSuperClass superclass];
    }

    return isMethodOverridden;
}
```

This can be called as follows:

```
[self checkIfObject:someObject overridesSelector:@selector(someSelector)];
```

Comment: I like seeing a pure Objective-C solution to this. I would have posted an answer using the Objective-C runtime C functions, but this solution is nicer, IMHO.

Comment: Great answer, also big plus for a pure Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent to `respondsToSelector:` that will do precisely this job for you. As you will probably know, `respondsToSelector:` works in the way that it will return `YES` as long as the class itself or any of its superclasses implements this method.

But why not just put an empty implementation of the method into your custom subclass, that way you make sure that calling it doesn't have any effect and doesn't call the same method in the superclass. Did you think about this?

**Update:**
While there is no method equivalent to `respondsToSelector:`, you might want to take a look at the **Objective-C Runtime**.  It's a library that allows you to inspect characteristics of a class *during* runtime (a bit similar to Java reflections). Check out the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getMethodImplementation).

Comment: Yes, it did come across my mind, but I guess that's quite poor code quality. Either way, thanks for your answers, I have to decide now what's best for my app.

Answer (score 1):

Not the optimal solution but you can keep a boolean member to your UIView subclass (let's call it `UIViewSub` indicating if the desired behavior is implemented by the class and check that boolean before using the method.

Your subclasses (those inheriting `UIViewSub`) will set/unset this member accordingly in its construction (i.e if it does override it with implementation or not)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on ZeMoon's answer, I found that there wasn't enough logic to satisfy all cases. I needed to add a check to ensure that instances of the next superclass in the loop implement the specified selector at all. Subclasses of `UIView` are one example.

```
while (objSuperClass != Nil) {
    isMethodOverridden = ([objSuperClass instancesRespondToSelector:selector]) && 
                         ([object methodForSelector:selector] !=
                          [objSuperClass instanceMethodForSelector:selector]);

    if (isMethodOverridden) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might ask `Why?! ‍♂️`… but if one night you find yourself looking how to do this in Swift 4 – this is how:

```
import Foundation

extension NSObject
{
    func overrides(_ selector: Selector) -> Bool {
        var currentClass: AnyClass = type(of: self)
        let method: Method? = class_getInstanceMethod(currentClass, selector)

        while let superClass: AnyClass = class_getSuperclass(currentClass) {
            // Make sure we only check against non-nil returned instance methods.
            if class_getInstanceMethod(superClass, selector).map({ $0 != method}) ?? false { return true }
            currentClass = superClass
        }

        return false
    }
}

class Foo: NSObject { @objc func mtd() {} }
class Bar: Foo {}
class Baz: Bar { override func mtd() {} }
class Qux: Bar {}
class Fen: Baz {}

Foo().overrides(#selector(Foo.mtd)) // false
Bar().overrides(#selector(Bar.mtd)) // false
Baz().overrides(#selector(Baz.mtd)) // true
Qux().overrides(#selector(Qux.mtd)) // false
Fen().overrides(#selector(Fen.mtd)) // true
```

Comment: Excellent reply, upvoted as Objective-C is less relevant these days. In answer to your question "WHY?". In my case there was a need to see if a view directly overrides touchesBegan so it is excluded from being part of gesture recognition. I had the ObjectiveC code, but no the swift. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it helped! Yes, had something of the similar nature with the `NSView`. Apple frameworks often check if a method is implemented / overwritten prior invoking it, seems like a common practice in certain situations… ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Using the runtime, you want to use the function 
Method

```
* class_copyMethodList ( Class cls, unsigned int *outCount );
```

This will give you a list to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted for Swift 4.0 (and added an optional baseClass BELOW which the algorithm looks for overrides):

```
extension NSObject {

    func checkIf(overrides selector: Selector, baseClass: AnyClass? = nil) -> Bool {
        guard var objSuperClass = self.superclass else { return false }

        var isOverridden = false

        while objSuperClass != nil {
            isOverridden = object.method(for: selector) != objSuperClass?.instanceMethod(for: selector)
            if isOverridden {
                break
            }
            objSuperClass = objSuperClass?.superclass()
            if objSuperClass == baseClass {
                break
            }
        }

        return isOverridden
    }
}
```