# Why overriding UIView.drawRect makes "calling -display has no effect" message to appear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, metal

*Notice: I don't seek to solve a practical problem. I ask out of curiosity.*

I have a custom `UIView` subclass that I use in the main view of the application. It has a metal layer class:

```
+ (id)layerClass
{
    return [CAMetalLayer class];
}
```

I noticed that if I override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method, an error message starts to appear:

`<CAMetalLayer: 0x17005dc70>: calling -display has no effect.`

What's more interesting, it appears even when I override it like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

Which, as far as I understand, couldn't have possibly make any difference at all, since such an override (that just calls base class) shouldn't modify program's behavior, according to basic principles of OOP.

What exactly this error message means? And why does it appear?

Comment: Perhaps because your CAMetalLayer doesn't set your UIView to its delegate the way the default CALayer would and its just letting you know that you're wasting your time in drawRect: because it's not going to be called...

Comment: @Jef Nope, it would be illegal for a layer which is the backing layer of a `UIView` changing the delegate. However, overriding `drawRect` actually makes a difference. They system actually checks whether the method is overriden or not.

Comment: Could you add some more code related to the layer? It's possible that a different line is the original reason for that warning.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` API is *old* and it is not a nice API. The interactions between `UIView` and `CALayer` are rather complicated. The interesting bit is that the system checks whether you are overriding `drawRect`. That's why there is this warning in `UIView` documentation:

> drawRect: - Implement this method if your view draws custom content. If your view does not do any custom drawing, avoid overriding this method.

There is no need to call `[super drawRect:rect]`. The superclass doesn't do the actual drawing. If you don't want to draw anything, remove the method altogether. If you want to draw custom content over the layer, don't call `super` (call super only if you know that the superclass has also overridden `drawRect`).

> If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation.

In your case I believe the call `[super drawRect]` does something that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: "the system checks whether you are overriding drawRect." how is it possible and why is it written that way?

Comment: "In your case I believe the call [super drawRect] does something that is not supposed to happen." that's not true, because I get the exact same result regardless whether I call super or not.

Comment: @golergka It's possible because obj-c is a very dynamic language with strong reflection capabilities. One method can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737116/check-if-subclass-overrides-a-method. The original reason was probably related to performance. Most of the layers are cached and not redrawn every time. Once you add custom code to the equation, the ability of the system to optimalize redrawing goes down.